# ionic2 - navpop back to first page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a app that need to guide user to step by step. I know we can use `navpop` and `navpush` to navigate trough pages. however, How can `navpop` back to the first page?

What I tried is to `pop()` back 2 times if I have 3 pages:

```
//html
<button (click)="gotoAdopt()">
    Back to Adopt
  </button>

//component.ts
gotoAdopt(event){
    // That's right, we're pushing to ourselves!
    this.navCtrl.pop();
    this.navCtrl.pop();///<-- pop() again to go back to first page
  }
```

But I think there are better solution than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NavController#popToRoot`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot)

> Navigate back to the root of the stack, no matter how far back that is.
>
> Returns a promise which is resolved when the transition has completed.